# Exception Handling notification : in VS2017 IDE or cmd window only

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have noticed that sometimes Visual Studio 2017 will display Exceptions within the IDE with a modal window.  ONe is then able to make use of Locals and the Watch window.  However, on a different computer (with seemingly same VS2017) the same code and same exception show only in the command window.
   How can I force the Exception to show within the IDE and not the cmd window?

Within IDE:

[image]

Only in cmd:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017

Comment: thanks Kevin.  I did see that article but it seems that it went over what exceptions to break on and what exceptions to NOT break on, as well as defining custom exceptions and how to handle them.  I didn't see anything in that article that showed how to display any of these exceptions.

Comment: This is pretty much the same thing. Visual studio will show the exception when the debugger break on it. Check your exception settings, and possibly disable "Just my code"